# Observable in Angular returns [ Object object ]

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I saw similar questions here but still cant get the point. In my service i have:

```
banner(): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.get<String>(`${SERVER_API_URL}/api/banner`);
}
```

In component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.principal.identity().then(account => {
        this.account = account;
    });

    this.registerAuthenticationSuccess();
    this.craCoreService.banner().subscribe(value => this.banner = value);
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" *ngSwitchCase="false">
   {{banner}}
</div>
```

My service method returns simple JSON object with single String property called "banner". But in UI i always get [Object object]. I do not understand **how to get value from it**. Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You might have to do like `{{ banner.banner }}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's an object with the `banner` property, then you need to use that use property in your TS code

```
this.craCoreService.banner().subscribe(value => this.banner = value.banner);
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But i have some trash in console now. Does it easy to fix, or can I ignore it? `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'banner' of undefined`

Comment: `this.craCoreService.banner().subscribe(value => { if (value) this.banner = value.banner; });`

Answer (score 3):

use `json` pipe to show the object in the template.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" *ngSwitchCase="false">  {{banner | json}}</div>
```